# Seeking Erdős' paper on 714 and 715

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Hank Aaron tied Babe Ruth’s home run record of 714 on April 4, 1974. He finished the 1973 season with 713 career home runs. On April 8, 1974, he broke Babe Ruth’s record by hitting his 715th home run.

Someone collaborated with Erdős on a paper about interesting and unique properties of these two numbers.

I am looking for that paper

Comment: Did you check the references in [Ruth–Aaron pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth–Aaron_pair) ?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comment by David S and Martin R. I found

Erdős, P. and Pomerance, C. "On the Largest Prime Factors of n and n+1." Aequationes Mathematicae 17, 311-321, 1978.

Thanks